# AS3 Change swf height with function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I create a document which has 990px width and 40px height. I create a button and when I click the button I want to swf height grow up to 250px. Like this: http://demo.linkz.net/LinkZmasthead/turkcell/gece_kusu/default.html

I tried to change stage height but swf height doesn't grow up.

```
var mc:MovieClip;
mc = this["buton"];
mc.buttonMode = true;
mc.mouseChildren = false;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // codes
}
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: You don't modify the SWF height, you modify the height of the container in the HTML page.

Comment: Should I solve issue like this?

there will be 2 stage which have different sizes. When I click the expand button stage2 appears and I change container size up to 250px.

When I click on close button container size will be set down 40px and stage1 will appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.display.StageAlign; 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode; 
import flash.events.Event; 

swfStage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
swfStage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeYourStage);

function resizeYourStage(e:Event):void {
    //resize code here
};
```

In your HTML add an onclick event to the button

```
<button type="button" onClick="StageResize.height = '250';">Resize</button>
```

[Here is an example](http://www.designscripting.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/StageResize.html). You can right click on the page to inspect the swf size changes.

Note: In an HTML page hosting the SWF file, both the object and embed tags' height attributes must be set to a percentage not pixels.